# How to cadd a swipe to refresh to my code?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have the following layout code in my xlm, to call my recycler view in my status fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.Status">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/statusRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I tried to call this  swipe to refresh using this in my main activity, but no sucessfull so now I am attempting to use in my fragment file, the one I used the xml to get the recyclerView,and here are the errors are showen:
**Unresolved reference: mySwipeRefreshLayout---
PackageManagerCompat.LOG_TAG can only be accessed from within the same library (androidx.core:core)---
Unresolved reference: myUpdateOperation---
Unresolved reference: mySwipeRefreshLayout---
Variable expected**

```
package com.example.whatsappstatussaver.fragments

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.content.PackageManagerCompat.LOG_TAG
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
import com.example.whatsappstatussaver.R
import com.example.whatsappstatussaver.adapters.StatusAdapter
import com.example.whatsappstatussaver.dao.Dao
import com.example.whatsappstatussaver.utils.Constants

class Status() : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_status) {

    private lateinit var path:String

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val sharedPref = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("dwa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        val bool = sharedPref.getBoolean("dwaBool",false)

        path = if (bool){
            Constants.STATUS_LOCATION_DW
        }else{
            Constants.STATUS_LOCATION
        }

        setupLayout(view)
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(object : SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{
            override fun onRefresh() {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout")
                // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
                // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
                myUpdateOperation()
                mySwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
            }
        })

    }

    private fun setupLayout(view: View){
        val filesList = Dao().getData(path, requireContext())
        println(path)
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.statusRecyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        val adapter = StatusAdapter(requireContext(), filesList)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only forgot to declare the mySwipeToRefresh element.
This is the corrected code, I implemented it inside an Activity and it triggers the myUpdateOperation() function fine.

```
lateinit var mySwipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    mySwipeRefreshLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh)
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener { // Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout")
        // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
        // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
        this.updateLayout()
        }
    }

private fun updateLayout() {
    println("Updated")
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
}
```

Comment: here are all the error it gives me, as I said I am new to it... **Unresolved reference: mySwipeRefreshLayout:::**  **PackageManagerCompat.LOG_TAG can only be accessed from within the same library (androidx.core:core),:::**  **Unresolved reference: myUpdateOperation,:::**  **Unresolved reference: mySwipeRefreshLayou:::t**  **Variable expected**

Comment: I will edite the question so you will be able to see the entire code

Comment: @MikaelDavid I updated my answer

Comment: it worked for me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write that

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```